# Select Multiple: How to select/unselect (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

1)I have no Javascript knowledge.

2)I am using a select2 (multiple select) bootstrap form.
3)I want to deselect the other options of a group if I click in one option of the corresponding group.

3.1)e.g.: If option values "2" and "6" are selected and then I click options "1" and "5", it should automatically deselects options "2" and "6".

Thanks.

```html
          <div align = "center" class="form-group">
            <label>Filtros</label>
            <select name ="Filtros" id = "Filtros" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Selecione os Filtros"
                    style="width: 100%;">

            <optgroup label="IBC">
              <option value="1">IBC_ALL</option>
              <option value="2">IBC_SIM</option>
              <option value="3">IBC_NAO</option>
              <option value="4">IBC_Nao_Mostrar</option>

            <optgroup label="CROT">
              <option value="5">CROT_ALL</option>
              <option value="6">CROT_SIM</option>
              <option value="7">CROT_NAO</option>
              <option value="8">CROT_Nao_Mostrar</option>

            </select>
          </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't require JavaScript. This is based on what the user types. To select multiples, `CTRL` or `SHIFT` must be held down. So, if I had previously selected 2 and 6 and now wanted to forget those and select 1 and 5, I would just press 1 (with no other keys pressed) and then hold `CTRL` and press 5.

Comment: There is no need for you to mark up your question with HTML as most of the formatting options can either be done with the toolbar or simply by hitting ENTER.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1) I am using this first multiple select form bootstrap: https://select2.github.io/examples.html. 2) It is not like common multiple select form that we hold CTRL do select the options.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Selecting options is done by users.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on me. If you check multiple choices from different categories, it automatically deselecting another choices from another category.
**Note:** Not working when user use `SHIFT` key.

```
<div align = "center" class="form-group">
<label>Filtros</label>
<select name ="Filtros" id = "Filtros" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Selecione os Filtros"
        style="width: 100%;">

<optgroup label="IBC" parent="1">
  <option value="1" childof="1">IBC_ALL</option>
  <option value="2" childof="1">IBC_SIM</option>
  <option value="3" childof="1">IBC_NAO</option>
  <option value="4" childof="1">IBC_Nao_Mostrar</option>

<optgroup label="CROT" parent="2">
  <option value="5" childof="2">CROT_ALL</option>
  <option value="6" childof="2">CROT_SIM</option>
  <option value="7" childof="2">CROT_NAO</option>
  <option value="8" childof="2">CROT_Nao_Mostrar</option>

</select>
</div>

<script>
var selected = {
    1:[],
    2:[]
}
var last_selected = 1;
document.getElementById('Filtros').addEventListener('click',function(e){
var parent = e.target.getAttribute('childof');

if( e.target.selected )
{
    selected[parent].push(e.target);

  for( var i=0; i < selected[parent].length; i++ )
  {
    var elem = selected[parent][i];

    if(!elem.selected)
      selected[parent].splice(i,1);
  }

  if( parent != last_selected )
  {
    for( var i=0; i < selected[last_selected].length; i++ )
    {
      var elem = selected[last_selected][i];
      elem.selected = false;
    }
  }

  last_selected = parent;
}
});
</script>
```